# Database using JSON Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I am new to Jquery JSON. I wanted to know is it possible to use JSON as a database to store data and retrieve data whenever it is needed. Like instead of using mysql,or mssql or anything else is there any way to use only JSON(i.e. .json file)??
If yes can you please guide me? if no can anybody suggest a better way to store data? 
And i need to know this for asp.net webforms.

Comment: Take a look at mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) instead of MySQL. MongoDB is based on "JSON" document storage. Example of CRUD with Mongo: [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/) and [find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) data.

```
db.inventory.insert({
  item: "ABC1",
  details: {
     model: "14Q3",
     manufacturer: "XYZ Company"
  }
})

db.inventory.find( { item: "ABC1" } )
```

Comment: Can it be used in asp.net webform??

Comment: yes with the mongo .NET [connector](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/).

Comment: Thanks a ton :) It was of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

From [mongodb.com](http://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson)

> The MongoDB BSON implementation is lightweight, fast and highly
>   traversable. Like JSON, MongoDB's BSON implementation supports
>   embedding objects and arrays within other objects and arrays – MongoDB
>   can even "reach inside" BSON objects to build indexes and match
>   objects against query expressions on both top-level and nested BSON
>   keys. This means that MongoDB gives users the ease of use and
>   flexibility of JSON documents together with the speed and richness of
>   a lightweight binary format. Read our MongoDB overview to learn more
>   about these features.

There is also a similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189849/whats-the-best-database-for-storing-json)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible and it depends, if it suits your requirement then go ahead and use mongodb. To have json as your datastore I would recommend to use MongoDB one of the popular NOSQL(Not only SQL) DB.

But if your data has lots of relation between different entities then it's not recommended to use MongoDB. 
Go through this article, it gives you detailed explanation when to and when not to use NoSQL DB

http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/